# Populating dropDown menu and fields with firebase(javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

is there a way I can populate a dropdown list with values stored in Firestore and have it's corresponding data exported to fields? For example, if I have a **name** of a person from my collection,and this name has his own **Email**,**workplace** etc.. could i possibly populate my scrolldown menu with the names,and when i choose a specific name,i populate several fields based on the information of that name?
i am asking as a complete beginner to NOSQL and coding in general,i am not sure if there's a guide or documentation that will help me to achieve what i want to do so any help is appreciated,

Thank you.

Comment: yes that can be done so whats the issue, that's the logic which you will have to write

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.